# Set field values to newly imported rows in PostgreSQL table with existing data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, csv, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL table with existing data, and needs to import all the rows in a CSV file into that table. I am using pgadmin3's Import tool to do the import.

[image]

**Question:** For the newly imported rows, how do I set the values for a specific column (not found in the CSV)? I cant do `UPDATE staging.tablename SET colname = 'somename'` the way I could when importing into an empty table. Or is this approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `COPY` command from `psql`. You can set a `DEFAULT` value for a column and omit that value from the `COPY` command, eg:

```
\copy tablename(col1,col2,col3) FROM 'thefile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

Alternately, you can create a new `TEMPORARY` table in PgAdmin-III wtih just the columns in the CSV, import the CSV into it, and use SQL like this to merge it into the main table:

```
INSERT INTO realtable (col1, col2, col3, colwithdefault)
SELECT
    col1, col2, col, 'some default value'
FROM tempcsvtable;
```

You can use this to calculate columns based on expressions, combine and split columns, omit some rows, etc.